# Understanding the concept of map() function using lambda expression

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

What does this `(x[1],0)` part transform?

```py
rdd.map(lambda x : (x[1],0))
```

Comment: The equivalent "normal" function would be `def f(x): return (x[1], 0)`. What *exactly* don't you understand in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item in rdd it creates a tuple. For that rdd item (`x`), the second value of that rdd item (`x[1]`), is placed in the tuple being created along with the number `0`.

I don't have pyspark installed, so I'm just using the built in map function to show how this transformation would work:

```
>>> rdd = ['ab', 'xyz', 'jk', 'pq']
>>> list(map(lambda x : (x[1],0), rdd)) 
[('b', 0), ('y', 0), ('k', 0), ('q', 0)]
```